# ActiveJob::DeserializationError (Error while trying to deserialize arguments: Can only deserialize primitive arguments:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-sqs

I am using AWS SQS for processing jobs. It throws

```
ActiveJob::DeserializationError (Error while trying to deserialize arguments: Can only deserialize primitive arguments: <ActionController::Parameters {"_aj_globalid"=>"gid://app/User/104"} permitted: false>)
```

while processing mailer jobs

I am pushing mailer jobs to SQS at model by deliver_later,

```
def send_otp_to_email
  EmailVerificationMailer.send_email_otp(self).deliver_later
end
```

At controller (which processes the post request),

```
 ActiveJob::Base.execute(params)
```

to execute mailer jobs

When I tried executing job on console. The job was successfully performed

Comment: You can't pass objects to the background ActiveJob workers, try to pass the id and then perform a query in the EmailVerificationMailer to retrieve the right object instead of passing `self` reference

Comment: I tried that too

Comment: @Rendrum You can actually pass objects to activejob workers in the latest version of Rails

Comment: Note that `send_otp_to_email` should not happen in an `:after_create` but in an `after_commit, on: :create`

Answer (score -1):

It seems you're trying to pass a Parameter object to the mailer.

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"_aj_globalid"=>"gid://app/User/104"} permitted: false>
```

You should pass just the User record with id 104.

Comment: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#globalid, We can pass objects as parameter to job?

Comment: He should not just pass the id. We have the capability now to pass objects. Its a nice convenience that later versions of rails added.